# Mostrar datos con filtro en consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql

Cordial saludo, estoy tratando de mostrar los datos de una tabla de búsqueda instantánea, el código funciona correctamente, había hecho la consulta de tal forma que me buscara en toda la tabla, hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora requiero hacer la consulta con un filtro(`REGIONAL`) y creo que tengo que realizar una consulta anidada, pero no me funciona. La idea es que al realizar la búsqueda solo me aparezcan los registros que son de la`REGIONAL`de ORIENTE. P.D: No coloco todo el código por ahorrar, por que como dije antes funciona correctamente y por ahorrar espacio.

La tabla que tengo es la siguiente:

```
+--------+--------+----------+---------------+
|  PLACA | CIUDAD | REGIONAL | FECHA_TANQUEO |
+--------+--------+----------+---------------+
|ABC-123 |CALI    |OCCIDENTE | 2018-04-21    |
+--------+--------+----------+---------------+
|DEF-456 |BOGOTA  |ORIENTE   | 2018-04-20    |
+--------+--------+----------+---------------+
|GHI-789 |TUNJA   |ORIENTE   | 2018-04-20    |
+--------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

`$q`es la variable del input en donde se escriben los caracteres para realizar la búsqueda.

```
SELECT PLACA, CIUDAD, FECHA_TANQUEO, SUM(VALOR) AS SUMA
FROM combustible 
WHERE PLACA LIKE '%".$q."%' CIUDAD LIKE '%".$q."%' OR FECHA_TANQUEO LIKE '%".$q."%' AND REGIONAL = 'ORIENTE'
GROUP BY PLACA  ORDER BY `SUMA` DESC"
```

La anterior consulta me muestra las ciudades de ORIENTE pero también me muestra algunas ciudades de OCCIDENTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claramente es problema en la predecencia de los operadores lógicos. Además, faltan operadores AND | OR en la sentencia.

```
SELECT PLACA, CIUDAD, FECHA_TANQUEO, SUM(VALOR) AS SUMA
FROM combustible 
WHERE 
-- necesitas definir cuáles condiciones pueden aceptarse juntas
(PLACA LIKE '%".$q."%' OR CIUDAD LIKE '%".$q."%' OR FECHA_TANQUEO LIKE '%".$q."%')
-- para que SIEMPRE se use este criterio, se deja por fuera del paréntesis
AND REGIONAL = 'ORIENTE'
-- fin del bloque problemático
GROUP BY PLACA 
ORDER BY `SUMA` DESC"
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda ya lo solucione, y debido a mis requerimientos hice un cambio en la consulta, agregando`PLACA`dentro del parentesis con el operador logico OR para que tambien pueda buscar por este campo, de esta forma: `(PLACA LIKE '%".$q."%' OR CIUDAD LIKE '%".$q."%' OR FECHA_TANQUEO LIKE '%".$q."%')`. Cambia tu respuesta para aceptarla.

Comment: me alegra que fuese de ayuda!